# Не запускается приложение через QtCreator с OpenCV

Tags: qt, opencv

Собрал OpenCV(4.5.1) с помощью MinGW, в .pro файл добавил хедеры и скомпилированные либы:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\OpenCV\build\include"
LIBS += "C:/OpenCV/bin/bin/*.dll"

#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
```

При этом если добавить в код хоть одну строчку из OpenCV, например

```
CvMat* mat = cvCreateMat( 1, 101, CV_32FC1 );
```

в qtCreator проект собирается, но при запуске вылетает ошибка.

```
Программа неожиданно завершилась.
Процесс был завершён принудительно.
```

Однако, если запустить собранный .exe, то все работает нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Надо указать имя либы точно   `LIBS += -LC:/OpenCV/bin/bin/ -lopencv` без расширения, но с префиксом -l

Comment: Можно и так `LIBS += C:/OpenCV/bin/bin/opencv.dll`

Comment: Положил либы в папку рядом с .exe, все заработало, видимо при запуске через qtCreator он не искал почему-то их по путям, указанным в path.